# nginx proxy pass subdirectory

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to setup a proxy to access an install of Rundeck through nginx with the following configuration :

```
location ^~ /rundeck/ {
            proxy_pass http://rundeckIP:4440/;}
```

The problem is that any link inside Rundeck would omit the "Rundeck" subdirectory.

So, links inside Rundeck look like that : http://mywebserver/menu/home instead of http://mywebserver/rundeck/menu/home

Tried many configuration with proxy_redirect and proxy_set_header unsuccessfully. This is the smallest configuration that get me through with basic connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your /etc/rundeck/profile. Somewhere you'll find the 'export RDECK_JVM' section. Add this option:

```
-Dserver.web.context=/rundeck \
```

Comment: Perfect all sorted! Had to modify `/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties` and change as well `rails.serverURL=http://mywebserver.com/rundeck/` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**How to set up Rundeck to run under SSL behind Nginx, in a separate directory, and on a non-standard port:**

In `/etc/rundeck/profile`, in the `export RDECK_JVM` section add the line:

```
-Dserver.web.context=/rundeck \
```

In `/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties` change the `rails.serverURL` setting to match the full address where your Rundeck will be accessible for the outer world:

```
rails.serverURL=https://mywebserver.com:8000/rundeck
```

*Note: do **not** to add a trailing slash in the above URL, otherwise Rundeck interface will not work.*

In Nginx config, in the `server` section that is already configured to run SSL on your non-standard port, add the following:

```
location ~ /rundeck/ {
    proxy_pass   http://localhost:4440;
    proxy_redirect http://$host https://$host;
}
```