# Can I use the vanilla rundeck docker image in a subdirectory of a webserver?

Tags: docker, rundeck

The way to put rundeck in a subdirectory of a webserver (domain.com/rundeck) has already been detailed out here: [nginx-proxy-pass-subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876908/nginx-proxy-pass-subdirectory/40819793#40819793)

It is possible to set those variables in the vanilla docker container?

---

The alternative would be to set it up using [Configurations Exhibit](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/tree/master/cloud). However that would mean that I am doubling up on effort maintaining a derived image just for those specific settings, which is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

This was a simple case of failing to RTFM:

> [RUNDECK_SERVER_CONTEXTPATH=/](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/bc5ac35d139e7a3609ac1fcd4d55babee9a2f280/docker/official/README.md#rundeck_server_contextpath)
>
> Set to path Rundeck is running under(i.e. `http://localhost/rundeck`). Useful if running Rundeck behind a reverse proxy under a path on the hostname.

This fulfilled the requirement to set `-Dserver.web.context=/rundeck` as mentioned in the linked question.

And then to address `rails.serverURL=https://mywebserver.com:8000/rundeck`, it looks like `rails` was replaced by `grails` since that answer was posted. There is also a config setting for that in the container:

> [RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4440](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/bc5ac35d139e7a3609ac1fcd4d55babee9a2f280/docker/official/README.md#rundeck_grails_urlhttp1270014440)
>
> Controls the base URL the app will use for links, redirects, etc. This is the URL users will use to access the site.

Comment: From Rundeck v3.3.x on, use `server.servlet.context-path` in place of `server.web.context`. See [Rundeck System Properties Configuration](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/system-properties.html#properties-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own image with some distro (as base) + OpenJDK 8+ Rundeck + Nginx. [Here](https://github.com/arildjensen/docker/tree/master/rundeck-standalone) you have a complete example (you just to need change to more updated components in the Dockerfile call). [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQjaJINkQXY) you've some documentation about Dockerfile use.

Comment: Thanks for the generic information about docker, but wouldn't that exacerbate the issue of: _doubling up on effort maintaining a derived image just for those specific settings_, in essence making it even harder on myself?

Comment: If you check the first link, you have a complete template to build Rundeck+NGINX image.